# Link behind dropdown is clickable, rather than the dropdown being solid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown, when I hover over it opens fine, but the links behind the dropdown are still visible and clickable causing me trouble as you can see in the gif below

[image]

My css for the dropdown:

```
.os-dropdown {
    background-color: #047bf8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 100px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate(99%, 115%);
    transform: translate(99%, 115%);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(4, 123, 248, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(4, 123, 248, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-align: left;
}


.os-dropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

My html for the dropdown is like so:

```
<div class="pipeline-settings os-dropdown-trigger">
    <i class="os-icon os-icon-hamburger-menu-1"></i>
    <div class="os-dropdown">
        <div class="icon-w">
            <i class="os-icon os-icon-ui-46"></i>
        </div>
        <ul style="">
            <li>
                <a href="http://help.mysite.com/tickets/9" target="_blank" class="">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="genericmodal" data-url="http://help.mysite.com/tickets/9/edit" data-title="Edit entry" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#genericModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-id="9" data-url="http://help.mysite.com/tickets/9" data-type="tickets" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteEntry" class="entryDetails">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete Tickets
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and to activate the dropdown I am doing the following:

```
    $('.os-dropdown-trigger').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');
    });
    $('.os-dropdown-trigger').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');
    });
```

How can I fix the problem, so the buttons in the background don't interact with my dropdown?

Comment: please add minimum valueable fiddle, your code is not showing anything. https://jsfiddle.net/8ycsg4h7/1/

Comment: Turns out I had a class for my tr that transforms on hover, thus 'leaving' the hover status of my dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pointer-events:none;` like :

```
.parent .os-dropdown {
   pointer-events:none;
}
.parent:hover .os-dropdown {
   pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Try something like :

```
.os-dropdown ul {
    z-index:1000; /* should be ok with an upper value than the next parent one */
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a position of absoulte or fixed then add z-index to .os-dropdown ul so its z-index is above the os-dropdown class.

```
.os-dropdown {
background-color: #047bf8;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 20px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 50;
bottom: 0px;
right: 100px;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
-webkit-transform: translate(99%, 115%);
transform: translate(99%, 115%);
opacity: 0;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(4, 123, 248, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(4, 123, 248, 0.5);
overflow: hidden;
font-size: .9rem;
text-align: left;
}


.os-dropdown ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute; //or try position:fixed.
z-index:60;
display: block;
}
```